# Is there a prohibition to pack on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, travel, hachana-prep-for-weekday

Say one is bored on a Saturday afternoon. Is it permissible--if one finds it entertaining--to pack his suit case when leaving on a long trip the following day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a general [Rabbinic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De%27oraita_and_derabanan) prohibition, called "*[Hachana](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hachana)*"<sup>1</sup>, against preparing on Shabbat for activities after Shabbat. Packing on Shabbat for a trip after Shabbat would seem to fall squarely within this prohibition.

<sup>1. See the [linked Halachipedia article](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hachana) for lots of detail and sources.</sup>

Comment: does this halacha apply to pleasurable activities as well? Great resource by the way!

Comment: The @username macro doesn't seem to work for the first few hours of the question.

Comment: @Ramin, If you comment on my post and start your comment with @-Myname, then the system assumes your @-ddress is redundant (since I get pinged anyway) and snips it out. I think this rule is lifted once multiple people have commented on the post.

Comment: Just another case of "it's not a bug it's a feature!" :)

Comment: I have understood an exception to the rule that you cannot perform permitted labor on Shabbos if it benefits a weekday exists.  For example, if you do not need the dishes you used for Shabbos lunch till after shabbos, you are not supposed to clean them, but if the presence of dirty dishes in your sink so distresses you that you cannot enjoy shabbos, you may clean them.  Likewise, if you are so stressed by the upcoming trip that you cannot enjoy shabbos, you can pack.

Comment: @Dennis, if you can point to sources that back up this understanding, I recommend that you post an answer.

Comment: I don't have the source in front of me right now, but it was in an article in the Yeshiva University "To Go" series.  I will look it up after shabbos.

Comment: I was unable to find the source, so I cannot upgrade my comment to an answer.  But I did come across some interesting discussions, at the OU website, http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5763/bereshit63/specialfeatures.htm and the torah.org site, http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/vayeitzei.html which contains the exception I alluded to, "In the case of a family simchah, for example, when used dishes may pile up and create a dirty, unsightly mess, it is permitted to wash the dishes since they are being washed for the sake of Shabbos and not for a weekday need."

Comment: "Likewise, if you are so stressed by the upcoming trip that you cannot enjoy shabbos, you can pack." -- I don't know that this is true.